# Swift compiler error: cannot find variable in scope

Tags: swift, xcode

I am facing a strange error when writing the simplest of swift programs in Xcode 12.0.1.
[image]

It says that it can't find T1 in scope when it is very much in scope. I feel that it must be trivial to solve this problem, and I tried ⌘ + ⇧ + K and closed Xcode and reopened, but the problem persists. Anyone knows how this can be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes there are ghost errors that seem to not go away, even when Xcode is closed and reopened, but are fixed by either changing the code then changing it back, or clicking build anyway and the build succeeds.

Otherwise, the color highlighting of `T1` in the return doesn't match in the variable declaration. That suggests name clashing. Are there any *types* or *global variables* called `T1`, even if there's nothing else in *your* code maybe it's a built-in type or similar? Try naming the variable differently.

Comment: It's not building too.

Comment: @tf3 I edited my answer, to include another possibility

Comment: I only have a main.swift file in the project and only this one function in the main file, apart from the import Foundation and print("Hello World!") statements

Comment: @tf3 Try renaming it anyway, to see what happens

Comment: plus I suppose even if there was a global variable with the same name, this should cause shadowing rather than name clashing

Comment: i called it f2 and it has now vanished! what was it due to ?

Comment: @tf3 Try typing `T1` somewhere again, right-click, jump to definition

Comment: Now I renamed it to T1 and it compiles without errors, just a warning  that T1 was never mutated, consider changing to let constant. Looks like a silly bug

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and was searching around, but couldn't find an answer to it so I'll share it here for others to find as well. For my part, I was creating a view in a package and was referencing that view from an app.

I got the `Cannot find [Type] in scope` and turns out I forgot to put the `public` attribute on the view struct.